# CACHE MANIFEST – in ASP.NET CORE 2 Angular 5.x SPA Template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a Project with the new ASP.NET Angular 2 SPA Template and I want to use a Cache Manifest to make the files offline available. I have added the file to the html tag =>

```
<html lang="en" manifest="datalog.appcache">
```

And I created the Manifest =>

```
#CACHE MANIFEST
#version 1.2
#CACHE:
dist/index.html

#style sheets
dist/styles.f5ed9033d9d067cfd178.bundle.css

#style sheet images
dist/assets/account-outline.png
dist/assets/arrow_left.png
dist/assets/arrow_right.png
dist/assets/green.png
dist/assets/kuettner_automation_logo.png
dist/assets/lock.png
dist/assets/lock-open.png
dist/assets/red.png
dist/assets/refresh.jpg
dist/assets/sync.png
dist/assets/yellow.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Fabrik.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Anlagenteil.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Motor.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Klappe_Ventil.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Regelklappe.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Messung_analog.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Messung_binaer.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Motor_6KV.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Motor_FU.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Motor_Simocode.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_Schaltschrank.png
dist/assets/TreeIcons/ic_SPS.png

dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_E_red.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_I_red.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_L_red.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_M_red.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_E_green.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_I_green.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_L_green.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_M_green.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_M_grey.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_L_grey.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_I_grey.png
dist/assets/CheckoutState/ic_E_grey.png
dist/color.c7a33805ffda0d32bd2a.png
dist/line.567f57385ea3dde2c9ae.gif


#javascript files
dist/inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js
dist/main.cf9482167d068fb87745.bundle.js
dist/polyfills.1457c99db4b6dba06e8d.bundle.js
dist/polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js

#fonts
#dist/roboto-v15-latin-regular.3d3a53586bd78d1069ae.svg
#dist/roboto-v15-latin-regular.7e367be02cd17a96d513.woff2
#dist/roboto-v15-latin-regular.9f916e330c478bbfa2a0.eot
#dist/roboto-v15-latin-regular.16e1d930cf13fb7a9563.woff
#dist/roboto-v15-latin-regular.38861cba61c66739c145.ttf
#dist/MaterialIcons-Regular.012cf6a10129e2275d79.woff
#dist/MaterialIcons-Regular.570eb83859dc23dd0eec.woff2
#dist/MaterialIcons-Regular.a37b0c01c0baf1888ca8.ttf
#dist/MaterialIcons-Regular.e79bfd88537def476913.eot
#dist/glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.woff2
#dist/glyphicons-halflings-regular.89889688147bd7575d63.svg
#dist/glyphicons-halflings-regular.e18bbf611f2a2e43afc0.ttf
#dist/glyphicons-halflings-regular.f4769f9bdb7466be6508.eot
#dist/glyphicons-halflings-regular.fa2772327f55d8198301.woff
#dist/fontawesome-webfont.674f50d287a8c48dc19b.eot
#dist/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg
#dist/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2
#dist/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf
#dist/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff

NETWORK:
*
```

But I get the following error =>
Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404) http://localhost:4934/datalog.appcache

Also when  I check the files under Network but I cant see that datalog.appcache file is requested.

[image]

Does anyone have an Idea what I’m doing wrong? Is there anything I have to do in the Project / Template or with webpack/-config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this. When deploying with the ASP.NET Angular SPA Template. It will ignore the Mainfest. So, the Error Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404) is extremely misleading because the file was not available for him. For now, I generate the File myself after ng builf, webpack, publish and copy it my self into the publish folder with a small application.
Maybe this helps someone else.
Regards
Michael